# Core Data save multiple related attributes at once

Tags: ios, core-data

I am building a very simple application with two entities: `Person` and `Categories`.

In my `AddPersonViewController`, I have a field for the person's name and a Table view with multiple selection enabled with predefined categories.

I would like to be able to select multiple categories and save them at once together with the person's name when I push the Save button.

I could find a lot of examples that save one related entity but no one for several at once.

EDITED

I select the categories and put them in an array then I save the user but it saves only the last category of the array.

Here is my save method:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

//saves the user name
Users *name = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Users"inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
name.userName =  addUserField.text;

NSError *error = nil;
if(![managedObjectContext save:&error]){
    NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
}

//saves the related categories
Kind *kind = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Kind"inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
for (int k=0; k < [_addCathegoryArray count]; k++) {
    NSString *kindString = [[_addCathegoryArray objectAtIndex:k] description];
    [kind setValue:kindString forKey:@"kindName"];
    [name addHasKindsObject:kind];
}
if(![managedObjectContext save:&error]){
    NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Saving is done on the context, not on individual attributes or entities.

Put simply, when you save, all of the changes you've made to the objects in the context are saved.

Comment: I guessed this, but is my save method I'm concerned of. I've edited the question to explain better the problem.